# Sensor data delivered twice and too slow

Tags: android, sensors

On a "WIKO Highway Star", model 15560ae, I have problems getting data from accelerometer and magnetic sensors.

Calling [SensorManager.getSensorList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList(int)), the shortest delay for accelerometer is 10ms, for magnetic 100ms.

I registered both sensors like this:

```
Sensor sensorAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorAccelerometer, 20000);

Sensor sensorMagneticField = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorMagneticField, 20000);
```

to receive sensor data each 20000 microseconds = 20ms.

But it happens something very strange.
When I log the received delay and data like this:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
       Log("acc: time = " + time + 
           ", delay = " + (now - lastSensorAcc) + "ms" + 
           ", values = " + arrayToString(event.values));

       lastSensorAcc = now;
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
       Log("mag: time = " + time + 
           ", delay = " + (now - lastSensorMag) + "ms" + 
           ", values = " + arrayToString(event.values));

       lastSensorMag = now;
    }


}
```

I get this output:

```
Accelerometer values in log:

acc: time = 21:30:13.556, delay = 84ms, values = -0,41 5,12 8,65
acc: time = 21:30:13.559, delay =  3ms, values = -0,41 5,12 8,65
acc: time = 21:30:13.560, delay =  1ms, values = -0,41 5,12 8,65
acc: time = 21:30:13.561, delay =  1ms, values = -0,41 5,12 8,65
acc: time = 21:30:13.562, delay =  1ms, values = -0,41 5,12 8,65
acc: time = 21:30:13.646, delay = 84ms, values = -0,58 5,05 8,74
acc: time = 21:30:13.649, delay =  3ms, values = -0,58 5,05 8,74
acc: time = 21:30:13.650, delay =  1ms, values = -0,58 5,05 8,74
acc: time = 21:30:13.651, delay =  1ms, values = -0,58 5,05 8,74
acc: time = 21:30:13.652, delay =  1ms, values = -0,58 5,05 8,74

Magnetic field values in log:

mag: time = 21:30:15.845, delay = 100ms, values = 12,60 -37,98 -23,34
mag: time = 21:30:15.846, delay =   1ms, values = 12,60 -37,98 -23,34
mag: time = 21:30:15.944, delay =  99ms, values = 12,00 -37,68 -23,76
mag: time = 21:30:16.045, delay = 100ms, values = 12,00 -37,68 -23,76
mag: time = 21:30:16.047, delay =   3ms, values = 12,00 -37,68 -23,76
mag: time = 21:30:16.145, delay =  97ms, values = 10,92 -37,62 -23,94
mag: time = 21:30:16.147, delay =   2ms, values = 10,92 -37,62 -23,94
mag: time = 21:30:16.246, delay = 100ms, values = 9,84 -37,80 -23,64
mag: time = 21:30:16.248, delay =   2ms, values = 9,84 -37,80 -23,64
mag: time = 21:30:16.345, delay =  96ms, values = 8,34 -38,46 -22,38
```

As you can see, the values are repeated.

New acc values are delivered every 80-90 ms (I asked for every 20ms!!), between the values are repeated (why, I don't need them!).

New mag values are delivered every 100ms (thats what I expected), but why the same values after 1-3 ms again?

None of the described problems exists on my other smartphones (Galaxy Alpha, Galaxy SII, Nexus 7, Galaxy A3, Sony Experia XA, Asus Memopad 10).

Comment: Side note:  your time calculation is wrong.  There's 2 times involved here-  the time the sensor reading occurs, and the time you process it.  You really ought to be using the time the sensor reading occurs, you're using the second.  THe time the sensor reading occurs is part of the event structure

Comment: Ah, good advice, thank you!